# make a glossy JFrame and JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I was reading through the java docs and found that it is easy to make a shaped windows, making them translucent and coloured as long as the platform is supporting such feature, but I couldn't find anything about making them glossy.

Is it possible in either awt or just swing to give frame or a panel a metallic look?

I know this might be a horrible idea from cross platform point of view, but I wanted to know if it's possible somehow without resorting to some third party libraries?

I have found a button gloss example here:
http://www.andygibson.net/blog/tutorial/glass-button-tutorial-in-java/
But it is not exactly a metallic look and if I replicate the method to use rectangles instead of circles it may scale poorly.

I've been looking at JavaFX but it seems to be a massive multipurpose package - an overkill if I just want one eyecandy.

note - if you give a minus, be so kind to explain why - else its just being a jerk. I see nothing wrong with this post and I did indicate what I looked at. From what I see I've fulfilled all formal requirements and this is not a subjective type of question.

Comment: Before closing, please consider that the request is valid and comes from the will to mimic appearance of some standard Windows 7 elements.

Answer (score 1):

What your requesting can only be handled by calling the Windows native API. You'd have to cooperate with the Windows DWM (Desktop Windows Manager) facility. Typically it's handled by calling the [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[image: MSDN Sample for Sheet of Glass effect]

Long time ago, I tried to mimic the glass (AKA Aero/Frost) effect using Swing. It was partially possible. One can easily write drawing code which handles this (and surprisingly even quite performant), providing that the drawing happens on the Java side.

That was possible with Swing (see [Glass effect for internal panes](http://www.centigrade.de/blog/en/article/frosted-glass-on-the-java-desktop/)) and should be even simpler with JavaFX.

However, to handle your precise request - the windows borders - one has to use the native WinApi. From my little research, I only found that SWT does this in limited way (but doesn't expose as publically accessible methods).

I tried to call the Windows Shell API through the JNA project. I successfully managed to change the glass area, but the effect was unpleasant: the Swing wasn't really well prepared (~JDK 7u5) to handle partially transparent JFrames. I remember, that the JFrame code, during a repaint, was clearing the Window using some color. I had to forcefully change it to other one (which matched the one I specified by calling the Windows API), but ended up in a visual mess.

I tried to debug it and I found that certain versions of Java have different code to clear the JFrame's content. So, even if I managed to correctly set the wanted color, it could easily break with the JDK update.

Comment: What if I set `setUndecorated(true)` - this should remove window decorator and borders - would it be possible to create work-around the limitations of swing? I can remove the default system windows, place image-buttons instead of the system ones - I can set the color by going `this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);` and finally add the `frameScore.setOpacity(0.7f);` The only **missing thing** would then be the shiny effect of glass or metal

Comment: Yeah, so I vaguely remember a problem here: the DWM uses a special color to mark something is being treated as glass. That was problem #1, to make Swing use the color for background. The swing would need to be instructed to *blend* with the background color in order to get what you want. I remember there were some mighty troubles with that.

Comment: So my only option is to resort to a large library that has its own window renderer and creates something like a virtual window within a panel OR apply a texture while sacrificing the transparency?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not really sure what your trying to achieve. If it comes to the "windows native glass" effect, then yes - you have no other possibility than somehow call the WinApi. The other effect - metal one - is not achievable this way. Do you have any reference screenshot of the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry about the delay, I had to disassemble my computer this weekend - well, I want something like that: [elevator panel](http://photos.gograph.com/thumbs/CSP/CSP307/k3075416.jpg) Notice the metal finish and glossy buttons

Comment: Oh, so it's actually simpler than I thought. You could use JavaFX or Swing to get the brushed metal texture and glossy buttons. What's left is only to round the corners of the main window. I'll look into it in the free time

Comment: Thanks! So I should just apply texture to the entire main panel frame and proper texture for buttons? Something like here [textured panel](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AJPanelwithatexturedbackground.htm) or should I actually go for javaFX (was thinking it's an overkill for just one panel)

Comment: Well, I don't know about JavaFX too much, but it promises declarative visual styling and I wouldn't be surprised that all of what's needed is provided out of the box (like gradients, dropshadow, thicke outlines)

Comment: I'll try it out then, thanks! Too bad I didn't know about it earlier - I might have used it for chart drawing as well instead of loading JFreeChart